# Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables

Tags: boot, kernel

i am using Ubuntu 16.04 and have this problem for about a week now, when ever i boot linux, or shut down linux, i get an arror message "Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables" which directs me to see information at systemd-sysctl.service
i went there and that's what written:

```
● systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ג' 2016-07-19 10:43:05 IDT; 12min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysctl.service(8)
           man:sysctl.d(5)   Process: 272 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 272 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

יול 19 10:43:05 maayan-blum systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables... יול 19 10:43:05 maayan-blum systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE יול 19 10:43:05 maayan-blum systemd[1]: Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables. יול 19 10:43:05 maayan-blum systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Unit entered failed state. יול 19 10:43:05 maayan-blum systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

i have not witnessed any effect on my pc by this error but i really don't know what effect it can have, and hoping to solving it somehow.
Thanks in advance!